# String and char replacement on a textview

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm doing on my translation app, I have some problem in my main translator.
for example like my code below, I try to transform "bed" into "bad" and if last char is "m" it will transform to "t".

When my input was "BEDROOM" I want to transform it into "BADROOT" that code below just read my first statement, and the other became false.

```
     private void MachinetranslatorO(){
     String change= input.getText().toString();
    if (change.substring(0,3).equals("bed")){
        String change1 = change.replaceFirst("bed", "bad");
        result.setText(change1);
    if (change.substring(change.length()-1).equals("m")){
            char replaceWith='t';
            StringBuffer aBuffer = new StringBuffer(change);
             aBuffer.setCharAt(change.length()-1, replaceWith);
             result.setText(aBuffer)
```

Comment: How many English words do you plan to translate? I can see an awful lot of if/then statements happening here. You might consider using a 2D Array as a translation table then iteration though both the input string and Array to accomplish a translation using String.replace().

Comment: Your indentation suggests that you forgot to close the brace for the block of first conditional, and perhaps the second one as well.

Comment: @DevilsHnd did you have any reference?

Comment: @user2570380 bracket didnt change anything btw

Comment: @LiamJuniors - See posted answer for and example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...since you asked I will provide a quick little Java Console runnable. The code is commented pretty good so you should have no trouble following it.

This application requires a text file containing Translation data (in this example: English To Spanish) which I have also provided sample data for at the end of this post.

Run the application and enter any one of the English words contained within the Translation Table data file (spanish.txt) and the program will display the Spanish equivalent.

Simply create a new project named **LanguageTranslator** using your favorite IDE then copy/paste the code below:

```
package languagetranslator;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LanguageTranslator {
    // Declare and intitialize some Class global variables...
    // The language. It is also the name of our translation table 
    // text file (ie: spanish.txt)
    private static String language = "spanish";
    // The 2 Dimensional Array which will hold our translation table.
    private static String[][] translationTable = {};


    // Class main() method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Load up the translationTable[][] 2D String Array from our
        // Tanslation Table text file (spanish.txt).
        readInTranslationFile(language + ".txt");

        // Declare and initialize our String variable we will use to accept
        // console input from User with...
        String userInput = "lets go";

        // Open a Connection to console Using the Scanner Class
        try (Scanner conInput = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            // Start a while/loop to continually ask the User to 
            // supply a English word...
            while (!userInput.equals("")) {
                // Ask User to supply a Word...
                System.out.println("\nPlease supply a English word to translate\n"
                        + "or supply nothing to exit:");
                // Hold what User enters into console within the userInput variable.
                userInput = conInput.nextLine();
                // If the User supplied nothing then he/she want to quit.
                if (userInput.equals("")) { break; }

                // Declare and initialize a boolean variable so as to later determine if
                // a translation for the supplied word had been found.
                boolean found = false;
                // Iterate through the translationTable[][] 2D String Array to see if
                // the User's supplied word is contained within. The English word to 
                // match would be in the first column of the array and the translation
                // for that word would be in the second column of the array.
                for (int i = 0; i < translationTable.length; i++) {
                    // convert the word supplied by User and the current word being read
                    // within column 1 of the 2D Array to lowercase so that letter case
                    // is not a factor here.
                    if(userInput.toLowerCase().equals(translationTable[i][0].toLowerCase())) {
                        // If the word supplied by User is found within the translationTable[][]
                        // array then set the found variable to true and display the spanish
                        // translation to console.
                        found = true;
                        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println("The " + language + " translation is: \u001B[34m" 
                                + translationTable[i][1] + "\u001B[39;49m");
                        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
                    }
                }
                // If we've iterated through the entire tanslationTable array and an a match
                // was not found then display as such to the User...
                if (!found) {
                    System.out.println("\n\u001B[31mThe supplied word could not be located within "
                            + "the Translation Table.\n\u001B[39;49m");
                }
                // Continue the while/loop and ask User to supply another word
                // until the User supplies nothing.
            }
        }
        // Exit the application if nothing is supplied by User.
        System.exit(0);
    }


    // Method used to fill the tanslationTable[][] 2D String Array from 
    // a text file which contains all the translation data.
    private static void readInTranslationFile(String filePath) {
        String line = "";
        int cnt = 0;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            // Read in each line of the tanslation Table text file so as to place each
            //line of data into the translationTable[][] 2 String Array...
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                // Skip past blank lines in the text file and only process file lines
                // which actually contain data.
                if (!line.equals("")) { 
                    // Each line of data within the Translation table text file consists
                    // of a |English word and it's Spanish equivalent delimited with a 
                    // Pipe (|) character. A pipe character is used because you may later
                    // want to add definitions to your data that may contain different types 
                    // of punctuation.
                    String[] tok = line.split("\\|");
                    // The redimPreserve() method allows for appending to a raw 2D String 
                    // Array on the fly.
                    translationTable = redimPreserve(translationTable, cnt + 1, 2);
                    // Add the file data line to the 2D String Array...
                    translationTable[cnt][0] = tok[0].trim();
                    translationTable[cnt][1] = tok[1].trim();
                    cnt++; // counter used for incrementing the 2D Array as items are added.
                }
            }
            // Close the BufferReader
            br.close();
        } 
        // Trap IO Exceptions from the Bufferreader if any...
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("\n\u001B[31mThe supplied Translation Table file could"
                             + " not be found!\n\u001B[39;49m" + filePath);
        }
    }


    // The redimPreserve() method allows for appending to a raw 2D String 
    // Array on the fly. I created this method to make the task esier to
    // accomplish.
    private static String[][] redimPreserve(String[][] yourArray, int newRowSize, int... newColSize) {
        int newCol = 0;
        if (newColSize.length != 0) { newCol = newColSize[0]; }
        // The first row of your supplied 2D array will always establish
        // the number of columns that will be contained within the entire
        // scope of the array. Any column value passed to this method
        // after the first row has been established is simply ignored.
        if (newRowSize > 1 && yourArray.length != 0) { newCol = yourArray[0].length; }
        if (newCol == 0 && newRowSize <= 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"RedimPreserve() Error\n\n"
                             + "No Column dimension provided for 2D Array!",
                               "RedimPreserve() Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return null;
        }
        if (newCol > 0 && newRowSize < 1 && yourArray.length != 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"RedimPreserve() Error\n\n"
                                + "No Row dimension provided for 2D Array!",
                                  "RedimPreserve() Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return null;
        }
        String[][] tmp = new String[newRowSize][newCol];
        if (yourArray.length != 0) {
            tmp = Array2DCopy(yourArray, tmp);
        }
        return tmp; 
    }

    // Used within the redimPreserve() method to copy 2D Arrays.
    private static String[][] Array2DCopy(String[][] yourArray, String[][] targetArray) {
        for(int i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(yourArray[i], 0, targetArray[i], 0, yourArray[i].length);
        }
        return targetArray;
    }
}
```

For a sample Translation Table text file you can copy/paste the following lines into a text editor and save the file as "spanish.txt" within the **Classpath** of your project (LanguageTranslator):

```
0|el cero
1|un
2|dos
3|tres
4|cuatro
5|cinco
6|seis
7|siete
8|ocho
9|nueve

a|un
able|poder
also|además
always|siempre
anyway|de todas formas
anyways|de todos modos
an|un
and|y
any|alguna
anybody|nadie
anything|cualquier cosa
apple|manzana

banana|platano
be|ser
because|porque
bedroom|cuarto
best|mejor

can|poder
can't|hipocresia

date|fecha

easy|facil

hard|difícil
harder|mas fuerte

now|ahora
never|nunca
new|nuevo

goodbye|adiós

hello|hola
her|su
high|alto
him|el
his|su
home|casa
how|como

in|en
inside|dentro
is|es
isn't|no es
it|eso
it's|sus
its|sus

leave|salir
list|lista
low|bajo
love|amor

of|de
out|fuera
outside|fuera de
over|encima

that|ese
the|la
then|entonces
these|estas
this|esta
those|aquellos
top|parte superior
topped|rematada
time|hora
to|a

was|estaba
weather|clima
what|que
where|donde
whether|si
who|quien
why|por que

you|tu
your|tu
```

Add data as you see fit to the file if you like.
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement works fine but after that you assign your new reult to change1 not change. So in your second if statement you should use the newer formed string - change1. Don't use the older string change in the second if statement.

Replace change with change1 in second if statement.

**EDIT - **

```
private void MachinetranslatorO(){
 String change= input.getText().toString();
 String change1;
if (change.substring(0,3).equals("bed")){
    change1 = change.replaceFirst("bed", "bad");
    result.setText(change1);

if (change1.substring(change1.length()-1).equals("m")){
        char replaceWith='t';
        StringBuffer aBuffer = new StringBuffer(change1);
         aBuffer.setCharAt(change1.length()-1, replaceWith);
         result.setText(aBuffer)
```